# Did Dragon Ball Heroes introduce a new super saiyan transformation?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

Episode 26 of Super Dragon Ball Heroes showed this state of Goku and Vegeta

[image]

It looks like Super Saiyan 4 but with red / grey aura. Is this supposed to be a new transformation? Or is it just a power up, a technique or a state?

Answer (score 1):

That's Super Saiyan 4 because it has red fur. The gray is possibly the transformation/fight (whatever they're doing).